# Restrict from moving to X axis (C# Unity)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have this example data

> Data: P, B, B, T, P

So it will be outputted like this

[image]

But what is happening to me is this

[image]

What I want here is that every tie must not increment to the X axis . How can I obtain that?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
string[] scoreboardWinner = new string[] 
{
    "P  ","B  ","T  ",
    "BP ","B P","B B","BB ",
    "PB ","P B","P P","PP ",
    "TP ","TB ","T P","T B",
    "TTT",
    "BBP","BPB","BPP","BBB",
    "PPB","PBP","PBB","PPP"
};

private void XandYaxis() {

    string[,] table = new string[104, 6];
    string newPreviousValue = "placeholder";
    int xIndex = -1;
    int yIndex = 0;

    if (gametable_no == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            newString[0] += list[i].r;
        }

        string[] newChars = newString[0].Split(',');

        if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (result.Equals(newPreviousValue) && yIndex < table.GetLength(1) - 1)
        {
            yIndex += 1;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        else
        {
            xIndex += 1;
            yIndex = 0;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
     }
}
```

I also tried putting an if else statement inside of the

```
if (result.Equals(newPreviousValue) && yIndex < table.GetLength(1) - 1)
    {
        string newResult = scoreboardWinner[2];
        if (previousValue.Contains(newResult))
        {
            yIndex += 1;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
     }
}
```

But it didn't work.

By the way the `scoreboardWinner[2]` = "T  "; which is the `TIE`

Comment: Try posting a bit more code. As it is now, everyone has to guess the origins of values of variables `newPreviousValue`, `previousValue`, `result`. Is this inside a loop of some kind? what is  `scoreboardWinner `?

Comment: @Tewr there i edited my question.

Comment: So, TIE should not increment the X axis? or new values that are the same as "newPreviousValues" should not increment X axis?

Comment: yes @mayo that's what i want

Comment: Are you updating `newPreviousValue` after setting a value on the board/matrix?

Comment: It is automatically updating . @mayo .

Comment: "It is automatically updating", I cannot see where...
Is a local variable in the method, so every time that you call `XandYaxis ` it will have the same value. 
Have you tried debugging your app? https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/monodevelops-debugger
Or just printing logs to see what code is being executed?

Comment: @mayo it's already solved thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-geometrical condition to stay on the same column is currently `result.Equals(newPreviousValue)`, which reads "the new result is the same as the previous."

You want the condition to be "the new result is the same as the previous, or the result is TIE."

Modify your condition to reflect this by replacing

`result.Equals(newPreviousValue)`

with

`(result.Equals(newPreviousValue) || result == "T ")`.